# Commas Around Names

Tags: commas

Would you write

The cruise liner Titanic hit an iceberg.

Or

The cruise liner, Titanic, hit an iceberg.

Thanks

Comment: Yes. It depends entirely on what you are trying to express. (Is *Titanic* essential or nonessential information?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does the appositive in this sentence need to be set off with commas?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/407047/does-the-appositive-in-this-sentence-need-to-be-set-off-with-commas) - *”Commas are used to set off an appositive when the appositive can only refer to a specific item.”* which in this case is certainly true