# His boss, Michael, or his boss Michael--which is correct?

Tags: grammar, punctuation, commas, titles

When referring to a title followed by the individual who holds that title, should I use a comma? For example, should I say:

At the end of a sentence *"his boss, Michael." or "his boss Michael.*

At the start of a sentence *"The writer, Michael," or "The writer Michael"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Titles like this are *appositives*: a construction where one noun phrase identifies an adjacent. Your question on comma use is almost a duplicate of [this one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/407047/does-the-appositive-in-this-sentence-need-to-be-set-off-with-commas), but a little broader, so I'll try to answer it in full. I'll quote the same style guideline as the top answer there:

Commas are used to set off an appositive when the appositive can only refer to a specific item. (The Chicago Manual of Style, 5:21,123; 6:22-24). Examples:

> Mary's son, Jesus, is thought by many to be the Messiah. [Mary had only one son]
>
> Dostoevsky's book *Crime and Punishment* is the great
> books of all time. [Dostoevsky wrote more than one book]

Your sentences fall into the same two categories: presumably, Michael has only one boss, and there are multiple writers. Thus we would write

> His boss, Michael, ...
>
> The writer Michael...

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate explanation. I actually didn't know the rule concerning appositives--I always thought that they needed to be set off by commas, but it's interesting that the comma only needs to be included when there is only one item being referenced.